# How do I make an Storyblok-API call with multiple parameters incl. "filter_by"?

Tags: json, api, parameters, silex, storyblok

So far I have seen, the API allows me to add certain parameters to my calls such as `filter_by` and `sort_by`.

This works well for me, but I would like to know how do I use multiple parameters at the same time and using the `filter_by` parameter.

Currently, I am working with the Silex-Boilerplate, which offers me this function:

```
options('{"sort_by":"name:asc","is_startpage":false}')
```

I have tried to pass this JSON as options-parameter:

```
'{"filter_by":"{"component":"reference"}", "sort_by":"name:asc"}'
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Are there any suggestions about how the JSON could look like?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see you're already using the options Twig helper which is the right way to go.

```
options('{"sort_by":"name:asc","is_startpage":false}')
```

you can use the filter_by parameter directly using this syntax:

```
options('{"sort_by":"name:asc","filter_by[component]":"reference"}')
```

Also this syntax would be possible:

```
getStories('starts_with', 1, 10, 'name:ASC', options('{"filter_by":{"component":"reference"}}'))
```

this will be mapped directly for the API call by our [PHP Client Library](https://github.com/storyblok/php-client). Those requests are also cached in your Silex Boilerplate without any extra effort.